# Solving for moments of $u(x,t)$ given the equation $u_t=xu+f\ast u$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, convolution

Given the evolution equation
$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}(x,t)=xu(x,t)+\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x-y)u(y,t)dy
$$
with initial condition $u(x,t)=\delta(x-x_0)$, is there a way to solve for either or both of the quantities
$$
m_0(t)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty u(x,t)dx \quad\text{ or }\quad m_1(t)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty xu(x,t)dx \quad
$$
in closed form, in terms of the positive-valued function $f(\cdot)$?

Comment: Have you tried taking the Fourier transform of the PDE to find an explicit solution?

Comment: @Mattos, thanks for the suggestion. I have tried both the Fourier and Laplace transforms but have not found them to be helpful (yet). The Fourier transform of this equation is $\dot{\tilde u}=i\tilde{u}'+\tilde f\tilde u$, which has the solution $\tilde u=\exp\left\{(t-i\omega)x_0+i\int_{\omega+it}^\omega \tilde f(s)ds\right\}$. Inverting this transform gives $u=e^{x_0 t}\mathcal F^{-1}_{\omega\to x-x_0}\left\{i\int_{\omega+it}^\omega \tilde f(s)ds\right\}$. Is there a way to evaluate the inverse Fourier transform of an integral like this?

Comment: Quick correction: Inverting the transform gives $u=e^{x_0t}\mathcal F^{-1}_{\omega\to x-x_0}\left\{\exp\left(i\int_{\omega+it}^\omega \tilde f(s)ds\right)\right\}$.

Comment: Integrating the original equation over $x \in \Bbb R$ gives a relationship between $m_0$ and $m_1$

Comment: @Dylan, thank you, that's a good point. Integrating the original equation gives $m_0'(t)=m_1(t)+F_0 m_0(t)$ where $F_0=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) dx$. 
Integrating with a kernel of $x$ gives $m_1'=m_2+F_0m_1+F_1m_0$ where $F_1=\int_{-\infty}^\infty xf(x) dx$ and $m_2=\int_{-\infty}^\infty x^2u(x,t) dx$. But in general, the dynamics of $m_i$ always depend on $m_{i+1}$, so it seems like a moment closure will not be possible.